# Update intent filter after registering broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have an `intent-filter` and a `broadcast receiver` which I am registering in `OnResume()` and unregistering in `OnPause()`. Now I need to add some more actions to intent filter dynamically.

Is it safe to update the existing `intent-filter` and register again? Or should I create a new intent filter and register that?

Comment: It makes no difference. In essence you need to register again if you change the `Intent` filter. Whether you create a new one or update an existing one makes really no difference.

Comment: While registering a new receiver, the broadcastManager keeps a reference to the intent filter. So if we update it again, that reference won't be affected?

Comment: I would need to look at the code, but I assume that Android does not keep a reference to the `Intent` filter, but actually a copy of the original one. If you modify it after registering a receiver, it probably makes no difference at all (ie: Android will not see this).